# Installed Ubuntu 14 on my Acer Aspire 4755G can't seem to install drivers. Help?

Tags: wireless, drivers, sound, touchpad, acer

So I bought a (relatively) new Acer Aspire 4755G. It didn't come preloaded with a OS so I thought it would be the best time to try out Linux. So I installed the latest Ubuntu and gave it a go. Everything is fairly solid except for the fact that the Wifi can't seem to work. The touchpad is freaking out even from swipe. Audio is also screwed.

Oddly, the bluetooth is working just fine.

I have zero experience with and I really want to try it out. But the I'm already tripping at the starting line. Mind guiding me to finding out how I can fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you. Please look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it won't be a solution to the touchpad issue or audio, but I've used that computer (have one actually, just got a 7560 though that I use instead) and you simply need to plug into ethernet and run `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` to get the wifi working. If you are simply having problems with the touchpad moving too quickly or something then search in the dash for mouse, then adjust the touchpad speed to what you like. Hopefully I was of some help.

Comment: I ran out of breath while trying to read this out loud.

Comment: so? I think he said it answered his question

Comment: You were looking for feedback as to why you're being downvoted. I'm providing feedback.

Answer (score 0):

To install drivers (I have seen that Aspire 4755G has NVIDIA graphics, so there will be NVIDIA drivers available to install) open the Dash (press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key) and launch **Software & Updates**. Go to **Additional Drivers** tab and select an NVIDIA driver (usually the one ***proprietary, tested***). If there are WiFi drivers available install them too.

To tweak the Touchpad, write "touchpad" in the Dash and launch **Mouse & Touchpad**. Change the pointer speed.

If your unable to connect to the internet, additional drivers will not find any available drivers, so if you cannot connect through wifi, try connecting an ethernet cable.